# If $K$ is subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: finite-groups

Question
1. Let $K\subseteq H\subseteq G$ and if $K$ is subgroup of $H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then  $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.
2.  Let $K\subseteq H\subseteq G$ and if $K$ is a  subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then  $K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

**Solution**
1. Clearly, $K\subseteq G$. Let $p,q\in K$. How can I show  that $pq^{-1}\in K$, to prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.
Also how can I prove the second case?

Comment: How is "subgroup" actually *defined* ? And what  *criteria* for testing this do you have available?

Comment: The second case must have a typo somewhere...

Comment: I have updated my post  with correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a- $pq^{-1}\in K$ because $K$ is a subgroup of $H$. Therefore $pq^{-1}\in K$ as a subset of $G$ and $K$ is non empty. So $K$ is a subgroup of $G$

b- $K$ is non empty because it contains $e$ as a subgroup of $G$. For two elements $p$ and $q$ of $K$ we have $pq^{-1}\in K$ because $K$ is s subgroup of $G$ and therefore as a subset of $H$ it is a subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 0):

do not be over-rigid in your approach. the $pq^{-1} \in G$ criterion is clumsy for a question of this type.

what you need is:
$$
A \le B \Leftarrow \Rightarrow (\text{A is a group}) \land (A \subseteq B) \tag{1}
$$
i.e. A is a subgroup of B **iff** A is a group **and** A is a sub**set** of B

solve your problem using this principle, then, if you wish, prove (1) using your preferred test